# Unable to debug app on android for Mi Note 4

Tags: android, debugging

I have been trying to attach my Xiomi Note 4 which has android marshmellow, MIUI 8.2. 
I have turned on USB debegginng option on my device but then too I am not able to debug application on my phone.

Not sure why this is happening.

Can anyone help me out on it ?

Comment: U are on Windows or Linux or OSX?

Comment: Could it be due to the drivers you have installed?

Comment: Have a look to this: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb.html

Comment: i was on windows machine

Comment: I have got resolution on this issue by reinstalling MI ui utility which contains driver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try restarting adb:
adb kill-server and then adb start-server in terminal

Comment: Thanks for suggesting me.  Restart of adb works but for some reason i had to restart my machine.  simple kill-server command on command prompt  didn't work well.

Answer (score 0):

The reason may be that ADB iterface is not installed in your device check [this link](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb.html) for detailed steps of how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned [here](http://c.mi.com/thread-171377-1-0.html) you have to turn off "Turn On MIUI Optiomization" option in `Developer Option` settings. It will ask you to restart you phone after that try to debug your app, it worked for me.